# Problema com abertura de tela modal usando bootstrap

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

sou novato na programação web, e estou com um problema na abertura de uma tela modal utilizando bootstrap. Basicamente tenho uma grid controlada por ng_repeat na qual tenho botões ao clicar no botão editar quero abrir a tela modal  contenha os dados relativos a linha do botão, para isso a chamada do botão foi codificada dessa forma (passando os valor lor data-whatever*). Contudo ao executar o programa ele passa somente o valor da primeira data-whaterver, as outra não são passada para a modal pela função (Editar-Modal).

Botão de chamada da modal:

```
            <div class="modal fade" id="Editar-Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Editar-ModalLabel">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="Editar-ModalLabel">Editar</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-nome" class="control-label">Nome do usuário:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Edtnome">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-empresa" class="control-label">Empresa padrão:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Edtempresapad">
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
<script>

/*Função para carregar a tela ao entrar*/

angular.module("cadastros", []).controller("cadpri-user-ctrl", function($scope, $http){

  $scope.users = [];

//var app = angular.module('cadastros', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
angular.module('cadastros', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);

var carregarUsers = function(){

        $http({
         method: 'GET',
            url: 'usuarios'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {

        $scope.users = {
                        cd_usuario:response.data.cd_usuario,
                        id_empresa_padrao:response.data.id_empresa_padrao,
                        ds_usuario:response.data.ds_usuario,
                        nr_telefone:response.data.nr_telefone,
                        nr_ramal:response.data.nr_ramal,
                        ds_e_mail:response.data.ds_e_mail,
                        fg_adm:response.data.fg_adm,
                        dt_inclusao:response.data.dt_inclusao,
                      };

        $scope.users = response.data;
        //console.log($scope.users);
        //setTimeout( 1000);

      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
      });

};

/*Função de excluir usuário*/
$scope.removeONUser = function(_user){
  $scope.users[0];
  $http({
    method:'DELETE',
    url:'userRemove',
    data:JSON.stringify({
                          ds_e_mail:_user.ds_e_mail,
                        })
    }).then(function(response){

    carregarUsers();

  }, function(){

});


//Função usando ng-submit

};

 $scope.ordenar = function(keyname){
   $scope.sortKey = keyname;
   $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
 };


carregarUsers();

});

$(document).on("click", "#sendsenha", function () {
        var info = $(this).attr('ds_e_mail');
        var str = info.split('|');
        var username = str[0];
        $(".modal-body #username").val(enailexibir);
    });

/*Funções javascript*/

function checkCols ()
{
  //var linha = document.getElementById("teste");
  var colunas = linha.getElementsByTagName('ds_e_mail');

  for (i=0;i<colunas.length;i++)
  {
  alert("conteudo da coluna"+i+" ->"+colunas[i].firstChild.nodeValue);
  }
};

$('#Editar-Modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  var recipientnome = button.data('whateverEdtnome') 
  var recipientempresa = button.data('whateverEdtempresapad') 
  // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
  // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('Editar o usuário ' + recipient)
  modal.find('#id').val(recipient)
  modal.find('#Edtnome').val(recipientnome)
  modal.find('#Edtempresapad').val(recipientempresa)
})

</script>`
```

Comment: Você tem mais de um elemento com a id #Editar-Modal? Ao utilizar o seletor com a tralha ('#'), apenas o primeiro elemento com a id é localizado (pois id's devem ser únicas). Se for o caso, utilize uma classe ('.editar-modal')

Comment: Olá lfarroco , respondendo ao seu questionamento tenho somente um id #Editar-Modal, o qual utilizo no botão de chamada do modal passando os data-attrutes. ( <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Editar-Modal" data-whatever="{{user.ds_usuario}}" data-whateverEdtnome="{{user.cd_usuario}}" data-whateverEdtempresapad="vair dar certo" data-toggle="tooltip-editar" title="Edidar o cadastro!"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></button>)

Comment: Sem ver o ng-repeat fica difícil, mas tente colocar um console.log( button) após o trecho "var button = $(event.relatedTarget)" para ver no console do navegador qual botão está sendo selecionado. Se possível, monte um https://plnkr.co/ com o seu problema.

Comment: Olá ifarroco, segue o resultado do console.log... "<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Editar-Modal" data-whatever="Alberto Aquino" data-whateveredtnome="aa_alberto" data-whateveredtempresapad="vair dar certo" title="Edidar o cadastro!"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></button>" podemos verificar que ele traz o valor na chamada do botão.

Comment: <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter:procurar|orderBy:sortKey:reverse" ng-controller="cadpri-user-ctrl"><td style="display:none">{{$index}} </td> <td class="text-left"> {{user.cd_usuario}}</td> <td class="text-center"> {{user.id_empresa_padrao}}</td><td class="text-left"> {{user.ds_usuario}}</td> <td class="text-center"> {{user.nr_telefone}}</td><td class="text-center"> {{user.nr_ramal}}</td><td class="text-left">{{user.ds_e_mail}}</td> <td class="text-center"> {{user.fg_adm}}</td> <td class="text-center" value="<?=date('d/m/Y')?>"> {{user.dt_inclusao}}</td><td class="actions" align="center">

Comment: Problema resolvido, o motivo pelo qual a passagem de variável não funcionava era a declaração das variáveis que estavam com um carácter maiúsculo e ao passar para o javascript ele o carácter era transformado para minusculo.